# How to convert Hexadecimal values into readable format?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, events, ethjs

I'm using etherscan API to fetch the event logs:

http://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=3147081&toBlock=latest&address=0x8685ab734df053d736164f5c07e22335ba7dda29&topic0=0xcded53d631ce4a38a1f90d59e5f2f9c023cd28c64aa66488e9462cc4a64a032f&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

The result is a Object with hexadecimal values:

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "address": "0x8685ab734df053d736164f5c07e22335ba7dda29",
      "topics": [
        "0xcded53d631ce4a38a1f90d59e5f2f9c023cd28c64aa66488e9462cc4a64a032f"
      ],
      "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000b579d4f1546d51980499aa96a2e411be3e449197000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
      "blockNumber": "0x30054a",
      "timeStamp": "0x5ae8016c",
      "gasPrice": "0x12a05f200",
      "gasUsed": "0x23aea",
      "logIndex": "0x8",
      "transactionHash": "0xb010aa74f66b00a9827044a3bfe4720bb1e057f243e5cae52307bafe2c2bb5d8",
      "transactionIndex": "0xf"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm calling API from my NodeJS server and tried `web3.toAscii()`, `ethjs.toAscii()` and `ethjs.toUtf8()` to convert the hexadecimals values into readable format- none of them working.

Only thing I can convert is hexadecimal numbers into readable numbers like blocknumber using `parseInt()`

Here's a basic structure of my contract code:

```
contract EtherBlock {
    uint256 public nonce;
    event eOpenPosition(uint256 indexed PositionKey, address indexed Opener, uint256 EtherTossed, uint8 OddEven);
    function OpenPosition (uint8 OddEven) public {
        emit eOpenPosition(nonce, msg.sender, msg.value, OddEven);
    }
}
```

Where am I lacking? How can I convert the event data logs into readable format? What is the 'decode' function in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let EVENT = [
    {name: "PositionKey", size: 256, indexed: true },
    {name: "Opener"     , size: 160, indexed: true },
    {name: "EtherTossed", size: 256, indexed: false},
    {name: "OddEven"    , size:   8, indexed: false},
];

function decode(data) {
    let event = {};
    let index = "0x".length;
    for (let i = 0; i < EVENT.length; i++) {
        if (!EVENT[i].indexed) {
            let name = EVENT[i].name;
            let size = Math.floor(EVENT[i].size / 4);
            event[name] = web3.toBigNumber("0x" + data.substr(index, size));
            index += size;
        }
    }
    return event;
}
```

Comment: I decoded the "data" field hex and the result and it returned a very long number. How can I read the event log data from that number?

Comment: @SowmayJain: You should split it into parts, according to the parameters that you pass in your event. I have a 'decode' function in Javascript if you're interested, but you'll have to rephrase the question, so that it would make an appropriate answer.

Comment: Question modified. So how can I decode that long decimal number?

Comment: @SowmayJain: Please provide your Solidity code, or at least the structure of the event that you emit in your contract.

Comment: The question is updated with the basic code. Thanks :)

Comment: @SowmayJain: The answer is updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you suggest any accurate article or course which explains the whole concept ot hexa to big number to whatever?

Comment: @SowmayJain: https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `web3.toDecimal(hexString)`

Hope this help.

Comment: I decoded the "data" field hex and the result is: 1.552518092300709e+231. How can I get the event logs in readable format?

Comment: you need to clarify what you data variable represent. it is indeed a large number just by looking the hexadecimal representation, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the parameters in the event emitted by smart contract. How can I achieve it?

Comment: you need to show your code and the definition of the event that produce this data

Comment: The question is updated with the basic code. Thanks Jaime.

Comment: the answer of @goodvibration seem correct, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Can you suggest any accurate article or course which explains the whole concept ot hexa to big number to whatever?

Comment: Everything in digital systems, like computers, is stored in the binary system and nothing else. The reason for this is that it has two symbols which can be represented in terms of physical quantities like voltage, 0 or 5 volts in the electronic circuits. Everything you see: Hex, Decimal, ascii, etc is just a way to visualize some binary numbers. The conversion from binary to any other system is just done for convenience. For instance, ascci assign a number to a letter, then we can store letters by storing the binary number assigned to that letter.

Comment: we do not use binary because "for humans" is not practical, for instance, 8 is '1000' in binary so decimal is more compact. However, decimal is also inconvenient for large numbers and Hexadecimal is more compact, for instance, 65535 is FFFF in hexadecimal. Now the functions to convert just to give you the data in the format that is more convenient for you. But remember there is nothing stored in the computer nor ethereum in hexadecimal, accii, decimal, etc,. Everything is in a binary representation, which actually means transistors opened or closed having  0 or 5v in some of their terminals

Comment: How can I convert this number into full number string - 1.552518092300709e+231? I tried this by using BigNumber() but it shows returns Invalid number.

Comment: if this is a bignumber,  lets say stored in x, you can do x.toString(10)